# How to iterate over columns in list of lists and change values without Pandas

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to square all floats in each column separately and then sum these. I get the column when I `print(column[1])`, but when I use another `for` loop it iterates over the elements in the rows instead of columns.

How can iterate over the elements in the column? I do not want to use Pandas.

```
for column in list_of_lists:
    for i in column:
        sum_of_squares = 0
        try:
            square_single = i**2
            sum_of_squares += square_single
            #print(square_single)
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

`list_of_lists` being:

```
[['', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood'],
 ['appel', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 ['gaar', 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 ['schotel', 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 ['amandel', 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
 ['deeg', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0],
 ['brood', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 ['suiker', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to break this down into a few steps: convert your table-style list of lists into a list of rows containing only the values you want to work with, then transpose the rows into columns, and finally find the sum of squares for each column.

```
table = [['', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood'], ['appel', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['gaar', 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0], ['schotel', 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['amandel', 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0], ['deeg', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0], ['brood', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], ['suiker', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]]

rows = [row[1:] for row in table[1:]]
columns = zip(*rows)
sum_of_squares = [sum(x ** 2 for x in c) for c in columns]
print(sum_of_squares)
# [18.0, 40.0, 24.0, 27.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little barbaric, but you can try this :

```
list_of_lists = [
    ['', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood'],
    ['appel', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ['gaar', 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ['schotel', 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ['amandel', 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
    ['deeg', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0],
    ['brood', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ['suiker', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]
]

print([sum(row[col]**2 for row in list_of_lists if isinstance(row[col], float)) for col in range(1, len(list_of_lists[0]))])
```

Output :

```
[18.0, 40.0, 24.0, 27.0]
```

Comment: Thanks though ;p It kinda works for me, but is it possible to skip the first column?

Comment: Sure you just have to add the **1** in `for col in range(1, len(list_of_lists[0]))`. I update my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to transpose the rows and columns of data and the then [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) the square of each of the values in each column of the result of that.

Here's what I mean:

```
def sum_squares(lol):
    columns = (v for v in zip( *[col[0] for col in zip(lst[1:] for lst in lol[1:])]))
    return [sum(val**2 for val in col) for col in columns]


list_of_lists = [['', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood'],
                 ['appel', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                 ['gaar', 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                 ['schotel', 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                 ['amandel', 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
                 ['deeg', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 5.0],
                 ['brood', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                 ['suiker', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]]


result = sum_squares(list_of_lists)
print(result)  # -> [18.0, 40.0, 24.0, 27.0]
```

Comment: Thanks you very much